# how to declare the type of the result of std::make_tuple, without using auto

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to implement a "Task" class, which can store a function pointer along with some arguments to pass to it. like std::bind(). and I have some question about how to store the arguments.

```
class BaseTask {
public:
    virtual ~BaseTask() {}
    virtual void run() = 0;
};

template<typename ... MTArg>
class Task : public BaseTask {
public:
    typedef void (*RawFunction)(MTArg...);

    Task(RawFunction rawFunction, MTArg&& ... args) : // Q1: MTArg&& ... args
        rawFunction(rawFunction),
        args(std::make_tuple(std::forward<MTArg>(args)...)) {} // Q2: std::make_tuple(std::forward<MTArg>(args)...)

    virtual void run() {
        callFunction(GenIndexSequence<sizeof...(MTArg)>()); // struct GenIndexSequence<count> : IndexSequence<0, ..., count-1>
    }
private:
    template<unsigned int... argIndexs>
    inline void callFunction() {
        rawFunction(std::forward<MTArg>(std::get<argIndexs>(args))...);
    }

private:
    RawFunction rawFunction;
    std::tuple<MTArg...> args; // Q3: std::tuple<MTArg...>
};
```

Q1: is && after MTArg necessary

Q2: is this way correct to init args

Q3: is type of args correct, do I need:

```
std::tuple<special_decay_t<MTArg>...>
```

according to this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple

// end of questions

1. I want Task can be used in this way:

   ```
   void fun(int i, const int& j) {}

   BaseTask* createTask1() {
       return new Task<int, const int&>(&fun, 1, 2); // "2" must not be disposed at the time of task.run(), so inside Task "2" should be store as "int", not "const int&"
   }

   BaseTask* createTask2(const int& i, const int& j) {
       return new Task<int, const int&>(&fun, i, j); // "j" must not be disposed at the time of task.run(), so inside Task "j" should be store as "int", not "const int&"
   }

   void test(){
       createTask1()->run();
       createTask2(1, 2)->run();
   }
   ```
2. task will only be run no more then once, that is zero or one times.

Comment: use http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/function/misc.html#idp60512544

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't allowed to use `std::tuple::special_decay_t` even if it exists: it is an implementation detail.  That code on cppreference exists for exposition only: it works "as if" that type exists.  If your implementation uses that code, that is an implementation detail that different compilers will not have, and the next iteration of your compiler is free to change/make private/rename/etc.

As exposition, it explains what you need to write if you want to repeat the special decay process of `std::make_tuple` and a few other C++11 interfaces.

As a first step, I'll keep your overall design, and repair it a touch.  Then I'll point out an alternative.

`MTArg...` are the parameters of the function:

```
template<typename ... MTArg>
struct Task {
  typedef void (*RawFunction)(MTArg...);
```

Here we want to forward some set of arguments into a `tuple`, but the arguments need not match `MTArg` -- they just have to be convertible:

```
  template<typename ... Args>
  explicit Task(RawFunction rawFunction, Args&&... args)
    rawFunction(rawFunction),
    args(std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {}
```

which the above checks.  Note I made it `explicit`, as if `Args...` is empty, we don't want this to be a converting constructor.

```
  void run() {
    callFunction(GenIndexSequence<sizeof...(MTArg)>());
  }
private:
  template<unsigned int... argIndexs>
  inline void callFunction() {
    rawFunction(std::forward<MTArg>(std::get<argIndexs>(args))...);
  }
  RawFunction rawFunction;
  std::tuple<MTArg...> args;
};
```

and then we write a `make_task` function:

```
template<typename ... MTArg, typename... Args>
Task<MTArg...> make_task( void(*raw)(MTArg...), Args...&& args ) {
  return { raw, std::forward<Args>(args)... };
}
```

which looks something like that.  Note that we deduce `MTArg...` from the function pointer, and `Args...` from the arguments.

Just because our function takes `foo` by value, does not mean we should make copies of it, or store an rvalue reference to it, or what have you.

Now, the above disagrees with how `std::function` and `std::thread` work, which is where `special_decay_t` comes in.

Usually when you *store* arguments to a function, you want to store actual copies, not references to possibly local variables or temporary variables that may go away.  And if your function takes arguments by lvalue non-const reference, you want to take extra care at the call site that you aren't binding it to stack variables.

That is where `reference_wrapper` comes in and the `special_decay_t` bit: deduced arguments are decayed into literals, which have conventional lifetimes.  Types packaged into `std::reference_wrapper` are turned into references, which lets you pass references through the interface.

I'd be tempted to duplicate the C++11 pattern, but force creators of a `Task` to explicitly `reference_wrapper` all types that are supposed to be passed by reference into the raw function.

But I am unsure, and the code to do that gets a touch messy.

Comment: Thanks. If user code want to store reference in my Task, i may tell them to use pointer instead, so i think std::tuple<typename std::decay<MTArg>::type...> is enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

> Q1: is && after MTArg necessary
>   `Task(RawFunction rawFunction, MTArg&& ... args) : // Q1: MTArg&& ... args`

No, it is not necessary, since it is a concrete function (constructor in this case). It would matter if it was a template function, then args would be of universal reference type.

For the same reason, you do not need to use `std::foward`.

> Q3: is type of args correct, do I need:
>   `std::tuple<special_decay_t<MTArg>...>`

Yes, because types should not be rvalues, if you want to store them in a tupple.

Comment: Not only is it not necessary, it also makes the ctor *only* accept rvalues for the by-value `MTArg`s, instead of allowing lvalues and copying them. And yes, he should use `std::forward`, for exactly those by-value args that then get moved. At least in the constructor. If the `run` function is allowed to be called multiple times, then definitly no `std::forward` in `callFunction`.

Comment: @Xeo But his tupple is not storing rvalues. What is the point of `std::forward`? Shouldn't `std::move` be used instead in the constructor?

Comment: No, that would also move the lvalue (reference) arguments. The `std::forward` only moves the by-value arguments into the tuple instead of a copy. Actually, the OP should probably `std::decay` all the types involved, since `std::make_tuple` also does that, making a copy. If he truly wants to forward all arguments and keep references, he'd have to use `std::forward_as_tuple`.

Comment: @Xeo But then both `std::move` and `std::forward` are not needed, since `std::make_tupple` will do everything properly. Isn't `std::forward_as_tuple` going to create tupple of rvalues?

Comment: `std::make_tuple` will make copies when you could also make moves - and yes, `std::forward_as_tuple` contains rvalue references, but those get moved into the member tuple.